# Python Finding stings in another program

Tags: python, process

i would like to ask for some help here. im not sure on how i could do this but here it what im trying to do.

I am trying to make a program that looks for a string in the program and tells me if its there or not.

if you have ever used [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) you can right click on the program you are looking for then right click and click properties. and filter then look for the line you are looking for. well i am trying to make a program that dose it for you so i don't have to keep going threw that all the mess in process hacker.

if someone could tell me what path i need to go or help me out here please do. if you need anymore info about this please let me know and ill be glad to explain more.

have a good one.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why use Python?

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
def textSearcher(string, wantedText):
    for x in string(or whatever has the text):
        if x == wantedText:
            return x
```

And you are talking about the control f function, right?